# What counts as a research experience in mathematics?

Tags: application, funding, research-undergraduate

I am applying for some scholarship that requires applicants to write about previous research experience.  As the application will be reviewed by the people of my field (mathematics), I would like to understand what do people count as research experience.  I have heard some people mentioning that research experience in the undergraduate level does not require original research, it could be of the form of summer projects (reading papers/books), dissertations (with/without original materials), going to conferences, organizing learning seminars and presentations etc.

Are all of the things I mentioned research experience?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, some people accept those as research experience, but would you be expected to have completed novel or original research - most likely not at this point.

But perhaps what they are looking for is relevant activity in the field, and if you are active with attending or organizing seminars etc etc then that may be what tips the balance in your favor compared to some other application.